# How do I truncate the transaction log in a SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server, logs

How do I truncate the transaction log in a SQL Server 2008 database?

What are possible best ways?

I tried this from a blog as follows:

> 1) From the setting database to simple recovery, shrinking the file
>   and once again setting in full recovery, you are in fact losing your
>   valuable log data and will be not able to restore point in time. Not
>   only that, you will also not be able to use subsequent log files.
>
> 2) Shrinking database file or database adds fragmentation.
>
> There are a lot of things you can do. First, start taking proper log backup using 
>   the following command instead of truncating them and
>   losing them frequently.

```
BACKUP LOG [TestDb] TO  DISK = N'C:\Backup\TestDb.bak'
GO
```

> Remove the code of SHRINKING the file. If you are taking proper log
>   backups, your log file usually (again usually, special cases are
>   excluded) do not grow very big.

Comment: OK, and what happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest and correct way to truncate a log file if the database is in Full Recovery Mode is to do a Transaction Log Backup (without `TRUNCATE_ONLY`.  This is going to be deprecated in future releases and is not advisable).

It sounds like you want to shrink your log file afterwards, in which case you'd run a `DBCC SHRINKFILE(yourTLogName)` command.  There is an optional second parameter for the requested size to shrink it to.

Answer (score 8):

You could backup the log to the null device:

```
backup log [databasename] to disk = 'nul';
```

Or you could switch the recovery model to simple and then back to full/bulk again.

Comment: I did + one on this because this is a tool in the dbas toolbox and your answer do not deserve negative votes I think. I agree with the sentiment that the best way is to take transactionlog backups but hey all good tools can be used in a correct way or in a bad way.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not care about your log data and just want to get rid of it:

Change the recovery model from full to simple, and then back to full. Shrink the file using [DBCC SHRINKFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189493.aspx) with the TRUNCATEONLY argument

The following command will change the recovery model from full to simple

```
ALTER DATABASE <databse_name> SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

The following command will change the recovery model to full

```
ALTER DATABASE <databse_name> SET RECOVERY FULL
```

To find the name of the log file you can use the following query

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('<databse_name>')
```

Shrink the file

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'<logical_file_name_of_the_log>' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

See [What is the command to truncate a SQL Server log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402/what-is-the-command-to-truncate-a-sql-server-log-file) for more information on this